# Google App Engine deployment smtp mail arguments

Tags: email, google-app-engine, deployment

When I run my Google App Engine app locally with

`dev_appserver.py --smtp_host=smtp.example.com --smtp_port=25 --smtp_user=ajohnson --smtp_password=k1tt3ns myapp`

with the correct details and project path, it works perfectly.

When I deploy the app, the email service doesn't work, obviously because I haven't specified these details.

How do I specify these details when I deploy so that the mailing service will work.

Answer (score 0):

The SMTP settings are only for local development. App Engine applications use the mail service when deployed. https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/mail/sending-email